# SAS PROC SQL; - creating DateTime variable

Tags: sql, datetime, sas, proc

I am trying to create a datetime variable for the past 3 hours... by concatenating `DATE` variable (in DATE format) and `time` variable (string hh:mm:ss) within PROC SQL;

Would highly appreciate any help with this!

Example:

```
APPLCTN_DT  =  05NOV2018:00:00:00.000 
APPLCTN_TM  =  20:04:57
```

I would like to create a numeric `DATETIME` field based on the above

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to produce a character variable, or do you want a numeric variable that can be used with SAS date and time functions? Please edit your question to include some sample input and desired output data.

Comment: Please post the data as text, not as images.

Comment: The date variable value appears to be a representation found in data bases (those 0's for the time portion).  Is your code running against tables in a remote data base ?

Comment: Looks like you already have a datetime value, not a date value, but it has zero for the timepart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like your "date" variable is really a DATETIME variable with zero time you perhaps can just add the time part to it?

```
new_datetime =  APPLCTN_DT + input(APPLCTN_TM,time8.);
```

Or just to be safe you could force the time part of your datetime value to be zero before adding the time part.  Here are a couple of ways.

```
new_datetime =  dhms(datepart(APPLCTN_DT),0,0,input(APPLCTN_TM,time8.));
new_datetime =  intnx('dtdate',APPLCTN_DT,0) + input(APPLCTN_TM,time8.);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the _DT variable is actually a datetime value with no exact time portion (thus just the date)).

Use `DATEPART` to extract SAS date value, `INPUT` to convert time string to time value, `DHMS` to construct a target date time value and `INTNX` to compute a new date time value offset from the target.

```
data _null_;
  APPLCTN_DT  =  '05NOV2018:00:00:00.000'dt ;
  APPLCTN_TM  =  "20:04:57";

  date_part = datepart(applctn_dt);
  time_part = input(applctn_tm,time8.);

  target_dt = dhms(date_part,0,0,0) + time_part;


  target_minus_3hr_dt = intnx ('dthour'
    , dhms(date_part,0,0,0) + time_part
    , -3
  );

  target_minus_3hr_exact_dt = intnx ('dtsecond'
    , dhms(date_part,0,0,0) + time_part
    , -3*60*60
  );


  format target: datetime20.;

  put target_dt ' combined';
  put target_minus_3hr_dt ' combined, 3 hours ago';
  put target_minus_3hr_exact_dt ' combine, exactly three hours ago (to the second)';
run;
```

Will show in log

```
05NOV2018:20:04:57  combined
05NOV2018:17:00:00  combined, 3 hours ago
05NOV2018:17:04:57  combine, exactly three hours ago (to the second)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is close to the result, i think you forgot to transfer SAS date format to display format.

using put function in variable target_minus_3hr_dt & target_minus_3hr_exact_dt, 
since the SAS date is shown as numeric so we need to use put function to transfer.

```
 data _null_;
APPLCTN_DT  =  '05NOV2018:00:00:00.000'dt ;
APPLCTN_TM  =  "20:04:57";

date_part = datepart(applctn_dt);
time_part = input(applctn_tm,time8.);

target_dt = put(date_part,date9.)||applctn_tm;


target_minus_3hr_dt = put((intnx ('dthour'
  , dhms(date_part,0,0,0) + time_part
  , -3
)),datetime20.);

target_minus_3hr_exact_dt = put((intnx ('dtsecond'
  , dhms(date_part,0,0,0) + time_part
  , -3*60*60
)),datetime20.);


put target_dt ' combined';
put target_minus_3hr_dt ' combined, 3 hours ago';
put target_minus_3hr_exact_dt ' combine, exactly three hours ago (to the second)';
run;
```